# Why are there questions about "media" in a PCI-DSS SAQ A?

Tags: pci-dss

The PCI-DSS SAQ A is used in the case where all payments are outsourced to an external vendor (conditions apply).

Despite that, [section 9](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1_SAQ_A_rev1-1.docx) of the questionnaire is about "media" (if they are physically secured, if their move follows policies, etc.).

**What specific media are they talking about**? All payment operations are outsourced so why asking about "media"? (I am asking not about the **nature** of the media (it has to be paper per requirements) but the possible **content**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any entity should also protect paper documents that contain **cardholder**
>   **data** in accordance with PCI DSS requirements 9.6 through 9.10. For
>   example, requirement 9.6 states "Physically secure all paper and
>   electronic media (including computers, electronic media, networking
>   and communications hardware, telecommunication lines, paper receipts,
>   paper reports, and faxes) that contain cardholder data."

What is cardholder data?

> Cardholder data (CD) is any personally identifiable information (PII)
>   associated with a person who has a credit or debit card

So what is PII?

> Personally identifiable information (PII) is any data that could
>   potentially identify a specific individual. Any information that can
>   be used to distinguish one person from another and can be used for
>   de-anonymizing anonymous data can be considered PII.

Consider receiving receipts with client information on it like addresses, names or other PII. That's the content they are targetting.

Comment: Thank you - very concise answer. We will not receive **paper** data but only **electronic** information  - which must not (per the requirements) contain any "cardholder data".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the reference for those quotes?  Doesn't seem like SSC phrasing.

Comment: @gowenfawr techtarget http://searchfinancialsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/personally-identifiable-information

Comment: @LucasKauffman Didn't see this answer before  I posted mine below. Stupid non-updating browser. Ah well. But one point I might make: despite the definition of the term "media" in the SAQ-A question, elsewhere the scope rules for the SAQ-A that specifically limit merchants who can use the SAQ-A to merchants who, at the most, have paper documentation containing cardholder data.

Comment: @halfinformed: I **can** get electronic information form my processor **provided** they do not contain "cardholder data". Otherwise e-commerce would not work (you would not get any feedback form the processor, no ability to get the country of the card for tax purposes etc.). From the doc: "*Merchant retains only paper reports or receipts **with cardholder data**, and these documents are not received electronically.*" (emph. mine)

Comment: @WoJ  Well yes, of course you can get electronic feedback back from the processor if it *doesn't* contain cardholder data.  I took you to be saying that you could do so, but could *not* get cardholder data back in paper form.  Which would be a transposition of the real meaning of the rule.  But certainly if there's no cardholder data in the electronic communications you're fine. Perhaps a reading comprehension error on my part to think you meant otherwise.

Comment: @WoJ Yeah, rereading what you wrote clearly a reading comprehension error on my part.  Whoops. Sorry. :)

Comment: @halfinformed: no problem, PCI-DSS is a nightmare on its own (not due to the difficulty but to the lack of clarity of the documentation)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question:   In [SAQ-A](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1_SAQ_A_rev1-1.pdf) "media" refers exclusively to paper documentation that contains cardholder data.  Know you mentioned in your question that you were interested in the *content* of the sensitive information that a merchant may store and not the *physical nature* of the media containing it, but in this case you must look at both elements together in thinking about what "media" really refers to under SAC-A.

The slightly longer answer:

Let's begin with what the text of the very first question in SAQ-A (on page 4 of the doc). In assessing compliance with PCI Requirement 9.5 card information storage protections, the document asks:

> Are all media physically secured (including but not limited to
>   computers, removable electronic media, paper receipts, paper reports,
>   and faxes)?
>
> *For purposes of Requirement 9, “media” refers to all paper and electronic media containing cardholder data.*

Now to any sensible person, that quick definition means, well, pretty much exactly what it says: "media" is used in a very broad sense of the term. Meaning any physical item (or at least any physical item separate or separable from a computer, probably) that stores or contains payment card information, whether the info exists on paper, in electronic form on a disc or drive, or in some other kind of medium.  So, the text of the definition we get in the actual questions of the SAQ casts a very wide net.

But here's the thing: for practical purposes in dealing with SAQ-A, the *real*, *practical* definition of "media" for a merchant is actually much narrower.

The confusion comes from a very understandable source: despite the above definition of "media" referenced in the actual question/ss about Requirement 9.5, the *scope rules* that determine what kinds of merchants qualify to use the SAQ-A *directly say that a SAQ-A merchant ordinarily shouldn't have payment card info stored on any "media".* The single possible category of exceptions?  You said it: paper documentation. Or in the exact words of "Part 2g -- Eligibility to Complete SAQ A" checklist in the SAQ-A document (page 3):

> Merchant retains only paper reports or receipts with cardholder data,
>   and these documents are not received electronically.

Bottom line: Yes, as used in SAQ-A "media" refers only to "paper reports or receipts". Despite the confusing, much broader definition also referenced* in the same SAQ. (And, FYI, merchants who *do* happen to have non-paper media with payment card data floating around in their operations need to take another hard look at the rules about who qualifies to file under SAQ-A.)

I know, it's enough to drive one mad. The wonderful world of PCI. :)

**Edit:**  The full SAQ-A scope checklist:

[image]